# Getting error when npm start with React application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-start

I'm having this problem whenever I create a new React folder using `npx create-react-app test`. `npm start` does not work and throws this error message in the terminal

```
> test@0.1.0 start C:\Users\franc\Desktop\test
> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.56.1/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\franc\Desktop\test\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000"' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\franc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-23T00_10_45_653Z-debug.log
```

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding `C:\Windows\System32` to the PATH in my environment variables and restarting the system.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in your package.json folder test `./test/package.json`
You will see something like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

If that is there run `npm run start` add the word `run`  - also make sure you cd into the test folder after you have created the app.

Comment: The "scripts" section that you have is the same as mine. Also, I did make sure I was in the right folder, but both `npm start` and `npm run start` give me the same error.

Comment: Try removing `node_modules` and than do `npm install`.